# doctrine 2 prevent LifecycleCallbacks caching of methods (or similar problem)

Tags: php, caching, doctrine-orm

I'm using doctrine2 (2.0.3) with codeigniter, and I noticed that when I add, change or even remove some methods that are anotaded as lifecycle, sometimes doctrine just ignores the change. For example, I add

```
/*
 * @PostLoad
 */
private function setUpObj() {
    echo('in');
}
```

To the Model (entity) that @HasLifecycleCallbacks, function sometimes is called on postload, sometimes it is ignored, sometimes it accept one change, then ignores any other changes...

In bootstrap file I use some of the config options, here is sample of them, if more needed I will update my post

```
    $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
$config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);
// Set up driver
$Doctrine_AnnotationReader = new \Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader($cache);
$Doctrine_AnnotationReader->setDefaultAnnotationNamespace('Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\\');
$driver = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver($Doctrine_AnnotationReader, APPPATH.'models');
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);

// Proxy configuration
$config->setProxyDir(APPPATH.'/models/proxies');
$config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');

    $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses( TRUE );
```

After some time, (usually when I give up changing the method, take a walk and come back) it starts to work normally, it accepts my last change and then I usually create what my intention was and stop changing that method.
My server is standard/default xampp on win7, and I never noticed anything similar to any other php files so far. This is not related only to @PostLoad, but it happens with @PrePersist and @PreUpdate as well

Is this normal behavior, or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance,
Dalibor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that notation and comment MUST be like this

```
/**
 * @PostLoad
 */
function setUpObj() {
    $this->mainObjName = 'models\Page';
    $this->defaultSortingField = 'ordering';
}
```

Meaning, first comment line must start with /** (two stars) and function cannot be private. Or at least this is how it works for me, hopefully it helps someone else

Comment: Yes, you need to use proper DocBlocks /** and the function must be public (otherwise it can't be called outside the class).